# How to delete a specific key value pair in firestore 9 modular?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the flowing object that I want to remove data-set-1 and keep the other sets is this possible in the context of the current nesting ?

```js
//Firebase object model
tracked : {
data-set-1: [11,3423,4232,23324,123,3123123]
data-set-2: [22,4434,4232,5554,123,3123123]
data-set-3: [33,3423,4232,23324,123,31553123]
}

const deleteData = async()=> {

const docRef = doc(db, 'data-users', currentUser.uid);
await updateDoc(docRef, {
tracked :{
['data-set-1']: FieldValue.delete(),
 }
});
}}
```

> caught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. deleteField() can only appear at the top level of your update data

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you show screenshots of the documents so we can better see that your code matches the data you have.  I'll note that your `docRef` is actually not a document reference, but a (sub)collection reference, and that your call to updateDoc might be failing with some error message (which you should provide here in the question).

Comment: @DougStevenson I posted a pic and I changed the code a bit.

Comment: Is it possible to simply update by passing only the 2 objects you want stored

Comment: This code could delete the upper object but I want to target the nested object.

Comment: Updating nested field under a top-level map field (tracked) requires use of dot in the key of the object you pass to update, as show in the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dot notation when using `deleteField()` on a nested field as shown below:

```
import { deleteField } from 'firebase/firestore';

await updateDoc(doc(db, 'data-users', currentUser.uid), {
  'tracked.data-set-1': deleteField(),
})
```